# Django select multiple date from calendar

Tags: django, select, calendar, date

Im new in using Django, and i want to know if there is some way to have a multiple date selection from a calendar,

i have multiple days :

for example a day is :

[ 28 july 2009 8:30 - 28 july 17h00 ]

Is there any way to do this with Django Forms

Thanks a lot

kimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is supported out of the box, but should be doable through a custom widget and some associated media. See the source for the [datetime widget](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L43) and [its associated media](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/media/js/calendar.js) for the current implementation. You should be able to base your solution off that one. By combining two dates into a single widget/field, you can create a date range. Also see the source for the [MultiValueField](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py#L747) and [its widget](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/widgets.py#L606), respectively.

Comment: thank you ! I will try.
with forms.DateField(widget=DateTimeWidget()) im able to select one.
Is is possible to use a MultipleChoiceField() with this

Comment: I don't think a multiple choice field is the right tool for the job; look into SplitDateTimeField & SplitDateTimeWidget.

Comment: But a SplitDateTimeField : Date is separated from the Time, we can add manually date and time in the correct format.
I think with a ManytoMany Field it will but possible to select multiple date, we have just to create from the admin interface the dates before.

Thank you for your replies :-)