# How can I use a multidate picker widget in django 1.11.3?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement a functionality which requires me to have multiple dates stored in a model field. Let me know if it is possible

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: how?? @hansTheFranz Could you please give me an example  or a link

Comment: if you want better answers write better questions. What have you tried? where are the error messages? Where is the code and at which points do you have a Problem? Nobody answers questions like this.

Comment: I tried implementing django-datepicker library but it doesnt work with 1.11.3. So i guess I am starting from scratch here so if you have any link to any documentation where i could start would be of great help

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-bootstrap-datepicker/1.1.1 looks quite promising. There you have examples and a documentation. You also can look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193114/django-select-multiple-date-from-calendar from SO. Good Luck :)